# Setting parameters when triggering a template deployment via ResourceManagementClient

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Is there an easy way of setting parameters in code when setting up a Deployment via ResourceManagementClient in code, without having to go via JObject?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434148/trouble-formatting-valid-jobject-for-withparameters-when-deploying-new-azure ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointer. I've generalised it a bit so the following converts a dictionary into the structure that the deployment request needs:

```
  public static JObject ConvertProperties(this Dictionary<String, Object> properties)
        {
            if (properties == null || properties.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            JObject Output = new JObject();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Object> TargetProperty in properties)
            {
                JObject Child = new JObject();
                Child["value"] = JToken.FromObject(TargetProperty.Value);
                Output[TargetProperty.Key] = Child;
            }

            return Output;
        }
```